# help with regex - how can i make some urls no-follow?

Tags: javascript, regex, nofollow

Ok so i've made this function which works fine for converting most urls like pies.com or www.cakes.com to an actual link  tag.

```
function render_hyperlinks($str){       
    $regex = '/(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|org(\.uk)?|tv|biz|me)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?&=#\+;]+)*)/ie';    
    $str = preg_replace($regex,"'<a href=\"http://www.'.'$3'.'\" target=\"_blank\">'.strtolower('$3').'</a>'", $str);
    return $str;    
}
```

I would like to update this function to add `no-follow` tags to links to my competitors,

so i would have certain keywords (competitor names) to nofollow for example if my site was about baking i might want to:

```
no-follow any sites with the phrases 'bakingbrothers', 'mrkipling', 'lyonscakes'
```

---

is it possible to implement this `if(contains x){ add y}` into my regex?

is this what is called a 'lookback'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe preg_replace_callback is what you are looking for:

```
function link($matches)
{
    $str_return = '<a href="http://www.'.$matches[3].'" target="_blank"';
    if(in_array($matches[3], $no_follow_array))
    {
        $str_return .= ' no-follow';
    }
    $str_return .='>'.strtolower($matches[3]).'</a>';
}

$regex = '/(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|org(\.uk)?|tv|biz|me)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?&=#\+;]+)*)/ie';    
$str = preg_replace_callback($regex,'link', $str);
```

Comment: this looks great however i'm having trouble with characters, it seems preg_replace_callback doesn't accept the 'e' modifier, so now it is capturing the 'n' form '\n' new lines?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input string? Hard to build blind regexp :)

Comment: ah it was my mistake, i was double escaping the linebreaks, your solution works fantastically, and thank you also to Marty for his help too